# Automate electrolyzer with AE 2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-industrialcraft, minecraft-applied-energistics

I've got a fairly complex AE2 setup, with IC2 automation, fluid importing and storage, and I'm trying to upgrade all my IC2 machines and automate some of the processes, as I'll need them in the future.

I've got bottlers set up to automatically create water cells, and now I want to automatically electrolyze them.

I set up the interfaces on the top of the machines, and import buses on the front, and tried creating elect. water cells. I've got the water cells, but somehow the water cells are not being put in to the electrolyzer.
I've tried putting the interface on the left-hand side of one of the machines, but all to no avail.

Is this simply not doable with electrolyzers, or is there some special trick?

I'm playing on a modified Tekkit Legends server (Minecraft 1.7.10; latest AE2, IC2 Classes verison 1.1.3.5)